# FLUTTER: how to set my Drawer background image width to Drawer width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

want to add a background image to my drawer. I want to fix my background image over Drawer width

```
 Drawer(
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      ),
    ),
    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset(
        "assets/images/menu.png",
        width: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Image.asset` in a `Positioned.fill(child: Image.asset ... )`.

This should make it expand to fill the `Stack`.

Comment: i tried left and right side not fit ..

Comment: Maybe wrap the `Image.asset` inside a `FittedBox` widget with the `fit` property set to `BoxFit.scaleDown`?

Comment: not getting you can you explain i urgently need

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Uehk3_wlY Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 Drawer(
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      ),
    ),
    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset(
        "assets/images/menu.png",
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
```

Comment: i tried still left  and right side not fit